# Is "This is my family" an acceptable response to "Who are they?"?

Tags: grammaticality, this-that, it-this

Context: suppose that I am looking at a family picture in an album in my friend’s house.

**Who are they?**

1. It’s my family. (correct)
2. That’s my family. (correct)
3. This is my family. (wrong)
4. They are my family. (correct)

Someone before told me that answer #3 is wrong. Do you agree? May I know why #3 cannot be a correct reply?

Comment: The person who told you that is simply wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "this" or "that"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237782/when-to-use-this-or-that) Also ["This", "that" and "it" difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258063/this-that-and-it-difference) as asked on English Language Learners, in case this gets migrated to where it *should* have been posted.

Comment: The words of #3 are not wrong, but something is off about *This is my family* at a friend's house.

Comment: If you are looking at a photo album, it is presumably close to you, so it's fine to say "This [photo] is of my family".

Answer (score -1):

context: I'm looking at your family picture

Laurel inquires, "Who are they?"[Quoted]

Laurel inquired who they are.   [Reported]

'Who are they?' - An interrogative sentence.

Wh- + an auxiliary verb (be) + subjective pronoun,

The answer would be, Subjective pronoun + verb (be) + object [Direct/Indirect]

i.e., They are my family.

> Therefore, option 4 is right

We know, Family is a collective noun.

It could be treated as an individual unit or as a collective one.

> Therefore, option 1 is right

since It [a subjective personal pronoun that agrees with singular verb]

We use the word 'this' to point out a person or an object which is close to you. On the other hand, 'that' is used to point out a person or an object which is farther from you.

Thereby,

> Option 2 & 3 are right.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question: 

Context: a friend is looking at someone else's family picture.

Whose family is this?
1. It's my family. (correct)
2. That's my family. (correct)
3. This is my family. (wrong)
Once a native English speaker said that #3 is not right. Do you agree with him? 
Do you agree that #3 is wrong? If yes, then why? Maybe the person who answers this question is near the photo and I feel that it's OK to use "this" here for "whose".

What do you think?

Thank you.